# How can I destroy a window (using tkinter) after a button in it was clicked several times?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
import tkinter as tk
def rand1():
    global rand_called
    rand_called += 1
rand_called = 0
games_number = int(input('How many games would you like to play? '))
m_gui = tk.Tk()
button1 = tk.Button(m_gui, text = 'Door 1', fg = 'green', bg = 'red', command = rand1)
button1.place(x = 20,y = 30)
```

I want the `m_gui` window to be destroyed after the `button1` will be pushed `games_number` times.
I tried this:

```
while True:
    if rand_called > games_number:
        m_gui.destroy()
        break
m_gui.mainloop()
```

but it wouldn't do the job.

please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the logic in `rand1`.

```
def rand1():
    global rand_called
    rand_called += 1
    if rand_called > games_number:
        m_gui.destroy()
```